# How to handle multiple exceptions in a Transaction with Ruby on Rails for importing a text file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.3

My ruby environment is: `Ruby 2.3.1` and `Rails 5.0.0.1`.

I'm trying to import a text file for import a lot of purchases items.

Example of purchase file:

data.txt

> Customer\tDescription\tUnit Price\tQuantity\tAddress\tSupply company\n
>   Athos Matthew\tChocolate\t10\t5\tSome address.\tChocolate company\n

The columns are divided by a tab (\t) and it has an enter at the final (\n).

I have the purchase class where all attributes cannot be null. The attributes are:

```
custumer_name:string
product_id:integer        # It has relationship with the Product Resource
product_quantity:integer
supply_company_id:integer # It has relationship with the SupplyCompany Resource
```

To import the file, I decided to create a PurchaseImporter class to do this job and keep the code cleaner.

My problem is that transaction part:

```
  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      purchase = Purchase.new
      data = line.force_encoding('UTF-8').split(/\t/)

      purchase.customer_name = data[0]
      product = Product.find_or_create_by!(description: data[1], price: data[2])
      purchase.product_quantity = data[3]
      purchase.product = product
      supply_company = SupplyCompany.find_or_create_by!(name: data[5], address: data[4])
      purchase.supply_company = supply_company

      purchase.save!
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    @errors[:import][index] = e.message
  end
```

My problem is that I want to catch all the raised errors from the Product, SupplyCompany and Purchase that could happen inside this transaction.

This is the order of the happenings without the unnecessary code to explain it.

```
product = Product.find_or_create_by!(description: data[1], price: data[2])
supply_company = SupplyCompany.find_or_create_by!(name: data[5], address: data[4])
purchase.save!
```

I need to print this errors information to this 3 classes in the screen, but with my code, I can only catch the first exception error, generated by the product. If some error happened in the SupplyCompany or in the Purchase, I lost these errors messages.

Are there other ways to import and log the errors message when importing files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have more specific exception handling... do a rescue for each section you want to trap, at the end raise an error if any previous error was encountered (to get you out of the transaction block) and test in that final error that you're rescuing your own `raise` otherwise it's some other problem and you need to halt.

```
begin    
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    error_encountered = false
    purchase = Purchase.new
    data = line.force_encoding('UTF-8').split(/\t/)
    purchase.customer_name = data[0]
    begin    
      product = Product.find_or_create_by!(description: data[1], price: data[2])
      purchase.product_quantity = data[3]
      purchase.product = product
    rescue Exception => e
      @errors[:import][index] = e.message
      error_encountered = true
    end
    begin
      supply_company = SupplyCompany.find_or_create_by!(name: data[5], address: data[4])
      purchase.supply_company = supply_company
    rescue Exception => e
      @errors[:import][index] = e.message
      error_encountered = true
    end
    begin
      purchase.save!
    rescue Exception => e
      @errors[:import][index] = e.message
      error_encountered = true
    end
    raise 'break out of transaction' if error_encountered
  end
rescue Exception => e
  raise unless e.message == 'break out of transaction'
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help.

This information was very helpful.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful.  You may not be able to vote but you can "accept" an answer (the option is there to the left of the question) if it solved the problem. Feel free to accept max pleaner's answer or my answer, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're rescuing `Exception` it's hard to know what error is actually emerging. When rescuing, you should try to use a more specific class when possible.

You also might not need to use rescue at all. The active methods you're using: `find_or_create_by!` and `save!` can be written without the exclamation point so that they don't raise errors.

In active record, if you try and save something with validation errors then the `<record>.errors.full_messages` array is populated. It won't necessarily raise an error if you don't use the exclamation point (although errors can be raised from all sorts of things regardless).

So, for example you can try and save a record and check for errors like this:

```
  product = Product.find_or_initialize_by(description: data[1], price: data[2])
  product.save
  errors[:import][index] ||= []
  errors[:import][index].concat product.errors_full_messages
```

Actually, in this case I think your approach makes some sense. You're saving a few records in sequence. If the first fails, then probably the others will fail - so is it worth even attempting to save those subsequent records? I'll let you decide.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the information. 

It was very useful to handle with my problem. 

I created this big array with errors.

Sorry for I cannot vote for you. I'm newer here.